# Active page links failing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu where I am trying to set the active page link to change style once clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 270px; float: left;">
    <span class="trowDark">
        <a href="index.php" title="Home"><span class="headerBtnMenu"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span><p>Home</p></a>
    </span>

    <span class="trowDark">
         <a href="list_emp.php" title="Employee List"><span class="headerBtnMenu"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span><p>Employees</p></a>
    </span>

    <span class="trowDark">
        <a href="list_doc.php" title="Document List"><span class="headerBtnMenu"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></span><p>Documents</p></a>
    </span>

    <span class="trowDark">
        <a href="list_cat.php" title="Document List"><span class="headerBtnMenu"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></span><p>Categories</p></a>
    </span>

    <span class="trowDark">
        <a href="list_not.php" title="Document List"><span class="headerBtnMenu"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span><p>Notifications</p></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.trowDark{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #637a91;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;      
}

.trowDark a{
    padding: 15px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    color: #637a91;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 4px solid #2C3E50;
}


.trowDarkClicked a{
    padding: 15px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #637a91;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 4px solid #b7d04e;
}



.trowDark:hover a{
    padding: 15px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #637a91;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 4px solid #b7d04e;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>

$('.trowDark a').on("click", function () {
    $('.trowDarkClicked a').removeClass('trowDarkClicked a');
    $(this).addClass('trowDarkClicked a');
});

</script>
```

I'm trying to target the div `.trowDarkClicked a` to show once clicked. It might be because this menu lives in a file called `sidebar.php` and it removed the active state once the new page has loaded but the `sidebar.php` is a constant page?

Comment: I don't think you want the a in $(this).addClass('trowDarkClicked a')

Comment: How is this going to work if your page is being reloaded? You have to keep track of the active link in another way.

Comment: But that's not why it's not working

Comment: I tried removing `$(this).addClass('trowDarkClicked a')` and when I click it loads the new page and the style isnt on an 'active' state

Comment: Just create your style, call it "wasClicked" and use $(".trowDark").toggleClass("wasClicked")

Comment: so wasClicked becomes which style sorry?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you are navigating away from this page, what purpose would be served by highlighting the link you have just clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the desired outcome?

jfiddle: jsfiddle.net/omikey/fhr644pz/

ps I couldn't find a thing wrong with your code, I just fiddled with it a bit.

be sure to use onready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.trowDark').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.trowDarkClicked').removeClass('trowDarkClicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('trowDarkClicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm let me fiddle with it

Comment: did you try wrapping the jquery in an on-document-ready wrapper? I'll add it to my post.

Comment: You might want to think about `preventDefault()` too

Comment: Sorry my Javascript is not too hot, where would the preventDefault() live?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the pseudo class :active?

trowDark a:active {

}

Comment: Could you show me from above how you would implement this as when I have tried the :active pseudo it does not work?

Comment: Nath, buddy, this should just be a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: I didn't have enough rep